# Why auto layout constraints not working?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm setting constraints in IB like [image: like shown in this image]

But when i run the app on iPhone4 it shows [image: like this image]

Why last three buttons not shown properly on iPhone4 screen?is there any mistake in my constraints ?
**Edit:-** This is my view hierarchy:-
 `UITabbarControlle -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController` and tab bar controller is `rootviewcontroller`.

**Edit:-** FYI there is no effect of any constraints on the screen(basically autolayout not working for me).

Comment: I guess the view is superview is sitting behind the tab bar..

Comment: Looks like you've laid out your Storyboard in a 4 inch layout but your iPhone 4 only has a 3.5 inch screen. So not an autolayout problem.

Comment: Yes i always do in that way.. and this is where autolayout comes in action.

Comment: @RoboticCat do you have any other idea?

Comment: I can't see all your constraints but as you have them setup it appears that you cannot fit your content on a 3.5 inch screen.  If you want to keep the spacing, you need to set each square to have `width = height` for all of them and also each square have the same height as one of the squares. Then alter the height of that "master" square by having it "squeezed" by the top/bottom constraints. Also, note other people's comments that orange constraint lines indicate issues which you should look at in Xcode (left hand view in Interface Builder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have designed the buttons on 4 inch and you don't have enough space on 3.5 for all of them.

One way to do this is to place scroll view over your view controller's view and add the buttons on the scroll view.You have to add constraint on the scroll view , to be fixed on each side (without width/height).

[image]

After that grab all the buttons and add constrains on each side and sizes , so they will be fixed

[image]

If you , on other hand, have enough space for all the buttons to fit in 3.5' without any top/bottom margins you can add the button in UIView (instead of scroll view). Place the buttons in the view and set fixed width/height on that view.Center the view and it will keep his size (with the buttons inside on both screen sizes) [image]

Comment: I don't want scroll view at all and there is enough space in 3.5 inch screen that all the buttons can fit.

Comment: I have edited my answer, can add screenshots in a while

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your constraints, you have to update them.

You can do as is shown on the image bellow:

[image]

Once done, you will see, the Orange lines under your buttons turned to blue.

I wish that helps you!

Comment: PS: You have the choice to select your buttons first then, click update Constraints, or, click Update All Constraints in View Controller.

Comment: Update constraints does updating the constraints as in the canvas

Answer (score 0):

Your view is probably within a `UIScrollView` which will extend your total contentheight. It is not related to the absolute height of your viewport.

However, what do you expect? Your 3 buttons would overlay to the next buttons, if your theoretical approach would work.

What you need to to do is to wire all buttons to each other and give the view a top and bottom constraint to the top and bottom layout. You probably need to adjust your view to be on full screen and not to extend to the bottom.

Hint: as long as something is 'yellow' you need to add further constraints.

Comment: No don't want that buttons overlay each other i'v shown only constraints for bottom buttons fro example.

Comment: have you fixed the size of each button? you may need to add a less-equal constraint to the space constraints