# UITextView text being centered left instead of being top left when Nav bar is put in View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

So i am having a little bit of an issue with auto layout. I am inserting a TextView into my VC and everything is normal..cursor and text start in top left hand corner. As soon as a nav bar is put into the VC, the text in the textview will lower to center on the left hand side, so basically it is just dropping it. I cant figure out what i am doing wrong, or a way to fix this. Any possible solutions? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783449/why-auto-layout-constraints-not-working